# Want to make a list of words using python where the student received a 0 for the word in that column

Tags: python

Relatively new to python, and programming in general, but want to take a student assessment list and iterate through each row then print a list that includes the student name and each word (column name) that the student missed (recorded as 0).

table looks something like this:

```
Name      -  ID - again - all - always - away - best - every
student1 - 13 - 1 - 0 - 0 - 1 - 0 - 0
student2 - 14 - 1 - 1 - 1 - 0 - 0 - 1
student3 - 15 - 0 - 0 - 0 - 1 - 1 - 1
```

Want to write something like this:

```
for row in dataframe:
  if row == 0:
    print student name +':' + column name
```

Output would be:

```
student 1: all, always, best, every 
student 2: away, best
student 3: again, always, away
```

I've got several hundred students and would love to just have a list showing which words each student needs to practice. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: This list is .csv or is this an Excel file or something otherworldly?

Comment: yes how exactly is the data stored? is it in python already?

Comment: It's stored as a .csv

Comment: Small detail, but do you expect the output to be 'student 1' or 'student1'? Given that the data file contains name as 'student1'

Comment: The output will actually just come out as the student's name as entered in the name column. I should have been consistent between the table and output above. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your table is in a Pandas dataframe (you should be able to import it using `pd.read_csv` or `pd.read_csv`:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([['student1',13,1,0,0,1,0,0],
                   ['student2',14,1,1,1,0,0,1],  
                   ['student3',15,0,0,0,1,1,1]],
         columns = ['Name','ID','again','all','always','away','best','every'])

df['wordlist'] = df.apply(lambda row: ', '.join(df.columns[row == 1]),1)
for line in df.Name +  ': ' + df.wordlist:
   print (line)

student1: again, away
student2: again, all, always, every
student3: away, best, every
```

Comment: This is perfect!  Just needed to change .join(df.columns[row == 1]) to .join(df.columns[row == 0]) to get what I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your table is a file, in the format described.

```
import itertools, csv

with open('studwords.csv') as f:

    reader = csv.DictReader(f, delimiter='-')
    students = []

    for line in reader:

        s = {}
        s['words'] = []

        for k, v in line.iteritems():

            key, val = k.strip(), v.strip()

            if key in ['Name', 'ID']:
                s[key] = val
            elif val == '0':
                s['words'].append(key)
        students.append(s)

for s in students:
    print '%s : %s' % (s['Name'], ', '.join(sorted(s['words'])))
```